# Magento 2.3 - How to bulk import attributes values?

Tags: database, import, sql, magento2.3.4

What is the best practice to bulk import attributes values. How to do it by hit tables?

Answer (score 1):

There are many style of import bulk value in magento 2.

1.) Export the csv file. And export csv file only two field like `sku field` and `your attribute field` and save two files csv. Again import the modified csv file import.

This is Example is how to import csv file :-

**https://www.mag-manager.com/product-information/magento-product-management/how-to-addupdate-magento-attribute-values-for-products-in-bulk/**

2.) And second Using `SQL`

```
select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code='your_attribute_code'; it will give you id of that attribute

select * from catalog_product_entity_decimal where attribute_id=82 // find that attribute value

update catalog_product_entity_decimal set value='' where attribute_id=82 and value='0.3'
```

3.) Follow this steps :-

- Navigate to **Catalog > Products**
- Select multiple products for which you want to update the product
  attribute value.
- From the mass action drop-down menu, select “**Update Attributes**“
- Change the value of product attribute by clicking on “Change”
  checkbox Click “**Save**“

Check this :-

[image]

And Finally your question is what is best practice to bulk import attribute values.i think third options is best.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Using SQL how to update bulk value, my attribute values count is 1000

Comment: Please check my answer i have already added.